# How to handle js loader with ActionCable websockets?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

So in my application using Rails 5 I have a loader system which caught `ajaxSend` and `ajaxComplete` to animate a loader in css.

```
$(document).bind('ajaxSend', () => {
  ...
})

$(document).bind('ajaxComplete', () => {
  ...
})
```

My question is simple, how to do the same thing with websockets ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function connectToYourChannel () {
    // start your animation here
    subscription = App.cable.subscriptions.create("YourChannel") {
        connected: function () {
           // this code will execute when you successfully subscribe
           // to your channel;
           // end your animation here
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: the connection process is extremely fast. You won't need a loading message in 99% of cases.